# error in newest rxjs during compile angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

i am new in angular and i am trying to upgrade the angular 4 to newest a ngular, 
i tried to make reusable a class method, to use it on many services and component

let say that this file called:

**./base-services.services.ts** :

```
getDataParam(url: any, params: any) {
    return this.http
      .get(url, { params: params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
      .subscribe(response => response);
  }

  createData(url: any, data: any) {
    return this.http
      .post(url, data)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
      .subscribe(response => response);
  }
```

and i use that base-services to extends on all services i make

**./getData.services.ts** :

```
export class LegalorderService extends BaseService {
  private token: string;

  constructor(http: HttpClient, auth: AuthService) {
    super(http);
    auth.isAuthenticated();
    this.token = auth.token;
  }

      getCart() {
         let params = { access_token: this.token };
         return this.getDataParam(
         Configuration.BASE_URL + Configuration.GET_SAVED_CART,
        params
         );
      }
}
```

and on the component :

```
updateValue() {
    this.legalOrderService.getCart().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.message != "ERROR") {
        this.localStorageService.store("legalOrder", response.result);
        this.localStorageService.store(
          "cartItems",
          response.result.order_details
        );
        this.cartTotal = this.localStorageService.retrieve("cartItems");
      }
    });
  }
```

do i wrong to use subscribe on that component from services ??

and after that i get error like this :

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts(16,3): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts(17,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts(17,44): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts(20,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts(20,44): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(124,5): error TS2411: Property 'constructor' of type 'Function' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(127,5): error TS2411: Property 'toString' of type '() => string' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(130,5): error TS2411: Property 'toLocaleString' of type '() => string' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(133,5): error TS2411: Property 'valueOf' of type '() => Object' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(139,5): error TS2411: Property 'hasOwnProperty' of type '(v: string | number | symbol) => boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(145,5): error TS2411: Property 'isPrototypeOf' of type '(v: Object) => boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
    node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(151,5): error TS2411: Property 'propertyIsEnumerable' of type '(v: string | number | symbol) => boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I can see in your code is , you don't need to subscribe multiple times , just remove the subscribe from the getDataParam method , because you are already subscribing in the component.

```
getDataParam(url: any, params: any) {
    return this.http
      .get(url, { params: params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: so i should not subscribe on that reusable class? and just subscribe it into a component?

Comment: @ZumDummi No .Just subscribe on your component

Comment: @ZumDummi You can apply other operators such as map on your reusable classes not the subscribe,

Comment: can u give me example using map on my resuable class?

Comment: @ZumDummi like this return this.http
      .post(url, data)
      .pipe(map(res=>res),catchError(this.handleError))

Comment: @ZumDummi in your case , no need to use map , unless you need a specific property from the response on your subscription result

Comment: how about if i want to check the respod on component ? so should i use map for this case?

Comment: @ZumDummi let's assume your response return from service is like { data:"ff" ,anotherData:"fff"} and you want only the data from it for your application , so you can use map(res=>res.data) , so when you subscribe you will only get the result containing in the 'data' property

Comment: @ZumDummi please mark it as answer if the solution works

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subscribe on a subscription:

- You first try to subscribe in `getDataParam`
- Then you try to subscribe again in `updateValue`

Remove `subscribe` from `getDataParam`:

```
getDataParam(url: any, params: any) {
    return this.http
      .get(url, { params: params })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: so i should not subscribe on that reusable class? and just subscribe it into a component?

Comment: Yes. When fetching data for a component, it's a good rule of thumb to subscribe in the component.

Comment: should we use map also?

Comment: What do you want to map?

Comment: to get json result